# Cant get selected item from a RadioButtonList in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, selecteditem, radiobuttonlist

I'm making an online test and have both questions and answers are in a SQL database. Everything is working great, except when the user presses the next button. In the code behind I'm trying to get the radio buttons selected value, but everything I've tried gets me nowhere. I've checked every StackOverflow answer I can find and have still been unable to resolve. Here's my code:

```
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCurrentIndex" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestions" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedQuestion" runat="server" />
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLQuestions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PCSCConnectionString01 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [QuesTxt], [QuesID] FROM [Question] WHERE ([QuesID] = @QuesID)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfSelectedQuestion" PropertyName="Value" DefaultValue="1" Name="QuesID" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <cc1:DataPagerRepeater ID="DPR1" runat="server" PersistentDataSource="true" DataSourceID="SQLQuestions">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="question">
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbQues" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuesTxt") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="QuesID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("QuesID") %>' />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlAnswers" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:PCSCConnectionString01 %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [AnsTxt], [CorrectAns], [AnsID], 0 as SV FROM [Answers] WHERE ([QuesID] = @QuesID)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="QuesID" PropertyName="Value" Name="QuesID" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <div class="answer">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLAnswers" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlAnswers" DataTextField="AnsTxt" DataValueField="AnsID">
                                <listitem>

                                </listitem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </cc1:DataPagerRepeater>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPrevious" OnClick="btnPrevious_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Previous" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNext" OnClick="btnNext_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" Text="Next" />
                </div>
```

Also, here is where I'm trying to get the value:

```
Protected Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Get Answer
    Dim rdValues As String = ""
    Dim Ans As Integer = 0
    For Each ri As RepeaterItem In DPR1.Items
        Dim rd As RadioButtonList = CType(ri.FindControl("RBLAnswers"), RadioButtonList)
        If rd.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            lblWarn.Text = "Select an answer to Continue!<br />"
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Pop", "openModal();", True)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        rdValues = rd.SelectedItem.Text (always NOTHING)
    Next
```

Things I've previously tried: Tried to trap SelectedIndexChanged (screen blinks, but never executes), tried putting OnSelectedIndexChanged on the RadioButtonList but it says invalid. Tried changing viewstate to enabled on the RadioButtonList and the MasterPage (no change). It just acts like nothing is selected.

I appreciate any help, I've spent hours and hours and hours, trying to get this to work. Need some secret sauce.

Comment: Just wanted to add, this IS in an UpdatePanel

Comment: I have implemented your aspx page / aspx code-behind and it works. I can get the selected index from `RadioButtonList`. So it looks strange...

Comment: @Li-JyuGao Thank you for your feedback.